# How to send JSON data that contains dash("-") in PHP/Laravel

Tags: php, json, laravel

I have an object which contains `error-codes` key. I want to send this data using `return response()->json(['error' => $results->error-codes])`. However, due to that dash, I am getting 500 Internal Server error.

I also tried `$results['error-codes']`. However, it gives me `Cannot use object of type stdClass as array`!

Please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
return response()->json(['error' => $results->{'error-codes'}]);
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you